# GitHub Actions workflow syntax not working as expected

Tags: github, github-actions, glob

I have a GitHub workflow that is triggered when files according to the
pattern `**/abc**` are modified / created.
As far as I understand it, this means that whenever a:

1. File that is in some subfolder of a folder that starts with `abc` or
2. Any file that starts with `abc`

is modified, the GH action should be triggered.
However, the workflow is even triggered when I e.g. create a file `repository/aaa/test_abc`

However, to my understanding, the file `repository/aaa/test_abc` does not correspond to the pattern `**/abc**`

Do I

1. Misunderstand GH actions syntax or is it
2. A Bug in GH actions?

Comment: Did you use quote: `'**/abc**'` like explained on the [filter pattern cheat sheet](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#filter-pattern-cheat-sheet)?

Comment: Yes I used quotation marks.

Comment: As `/` is a special character in regex, the syntax might be different. If it was a regex pattern you would have to add a \ before the / to do something like this: `\/abc`. However, I'm not sure it will work here as the syntax used with `**` on GHA seems a bit different. I will make some tests.

Comment: @GuiFalourd `/` is not any special regex metacharacter. It is often escaped in regex literal notation only because it is used as a regex delimiter char. If regex literal notation is not used, no need to escape `/`.

Comment: `**/abc**` is not a regex pattern. No regex should start with a quantifier. This is a glob pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @Wiktor between the regex and glob pattern difference. I wasn't aware of it.

Comment: I tested using `'**\/abc**'` @Sebastian and it seems to work as expected: adding `repository/aaa/test_abc.txt` didn't trigger the workflow, but adding or removing / updating `repository/aaa/abc/test.txt` did.

Comment: Thanks you @GuiFalourd It is not clear from the GH action docs that you have to escape /

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the `/` with a `\` for the pattern to work.

Using `'**\/abc**'` will resolve the problem.

Most of the time, the [filter pattern cheat sheet for the Github Documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#filter-pattern-cheat-sheet) helps to configure the paths, but in that specific case it wasn't detailed.