# Github Actions pull_request when base branch has name "something/*", not target branch

Tags: github-actions

Trying to get a GitHub action to trigger when the name of the branch that the PR comes from has a specific pattern.

Normally you can do this;

```yaml
name: My action name
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - 'something/**'

# ... the rest of the action
```

This will make the action trigger when a pull request tries to merge into a branch named `something/any-string-here`, however, I want the reverse. I want this action to run when the base branch has this name, regardless of what the target branch is.

Can this be done? Or do I have to add `if`-statements to all the steps checking the branch name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/` is a special character when used on `paths` or `branches` trigger fields.

In that case, similarly with what can be done in regex, you need to escape it with a `\`.

Therefore, to achieve what you want, you would need to use:

```yaml
name: My action name
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - 'something\/**'

# ... the rest of the action
```

*Note: [It's similar to this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70101203/github-actions-workflow-syntax-not-working-as-expected?noredirect=1#70101203)*

---

I tested it with [this PR](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/pull/30) which triggered [this workflow](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/workflows/workflow-tester15.yml).

Comment: thanks for the testing, but the test you are doing is merging from `something/test2` into `something/test`, but this causes the action to trigger. Try `something/test2` into `other`.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the `pull_request` trigger works that way. It triggers from any branch to the specified ones informed in the `branches` field. If this field is not informed, it will trigger for every branch.

Comment: I took the liberty of creating an example PR on your repo; https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/pull/31  And it turns out that the action does indeed trigger, and the syntax-issue seems to the the cause. Curiously, this trick does not work on my original problem-branch..

Comment: We both learned something today then :D